# React native expo: deep link / url scheme to send instagram direct message

Tags: reactjs, react-native, instagram, deep-linking

I'm looking for a way to send a direct message on instagram from my app using url schemes, this is the example of whatsapp

```
let url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + msg;
```

I basically want to do the same for instagram. Anyone ever find a solution for this ?

Thank you,